# Remove first row conditionally

Tags: r

This is a very simple problem and I'll probably catch flame for asking this, but I've looked everywhere and I can't find the answer... Or a different approach to my code.

I need to remove the first row of a data frame if the value of the first row and third column are equal to one.

This is what I have so far:

```
if (foo[1, 3] == 1) {
    foo <- foo[-1, ]
}
```

Is there a different way to do this using only bracket subsetting (avoiding using an `if` statement)?

Edit:

Edited for clarity.

Comment: You can put `-1` instead of `2:nrow(foo)` ...

Comment: Duh! Slight improvement though, I was thinking more along the lines of 1 line of code...

Comment: Well, write it in one line. You need to define "better".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you wrote doesn't remove the first row permanently, it only prints it out.  Change that with `foo<-foo[-1, ]`

Additionally, the code within the if-statement brackets is only one line anyway, you don't technically need them, but some like them for clarity purposes

```
if (foo[1, 3] == 1) foo <- foo[-1, ]
```

Comment: Thanks emudrak, but is there any way to avoid the `if` statement?

Comment: You can also(personally find it more elegant)  `foo <- if (foo[1, 3] == 1) foo[-1, ]`

Comment: Thanks @agstudy, it looks like what I have plus your and emudrak's suggestions will have to do. I'll let the question sit for a bit more and accept this answer if no one else has something.

Comment: Just curious= why don't you want to use if?

Comment: I keep thinking there is a way to do it using something like `foo[1, foo[,3] != 1]`.

Comment: @amzu So in that case just stop thinking ...

Comment: I knew I was going to catch flame for asking this. But @agstudy, aren't you a little bit curious to know if there is a different approach?

Comment: @amzu You could do `foo[ c(foo[1, 3] == 1, rep(T, nrow(foo) - 1)) ]`. There's no `if`, but it's much less clear. An `if` statement is easy for someone else (or you in two months) to interpret. This code dodges the `if` and hides the intent pretty well too.